# Why have i received a message that wasnt sent from the said sender?

Tags: sms

I received a message in error yesterday, i am using the Samsung Galaxy. It wasnt sent by my friend, who i was chatting with over sms at that time, but i still received it and it shows time of sending at that time itself. I believe had received the same message from my friend around 2 months back, it may be the same message. Has this happened with anyone else?

Comment: There was a sms bug a few months back but I thought it got fixed...

Comment: @Daniel depends on whether your OS has been updated since the bugs were fixed. Amazingly with Gingerbread already going out to many Galaxy S's, there are people who's phone companies haven't allowed them to upgrade since Eclair!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is not in your phone, or your friend's one. Maybe the error is from your provider, or the provider of your friend.

In some situations the network will not deliver a SMS due to overload, or many other causes, if this occurs some carriers delay the deliver some time, maybe this is the case, the network detected some problem and delayed the delivery of the SMS, and now you received a message send some time ago (like sometimes happens on December 31th with overloaded networks, you end up receiving a "Happy new year!!" on January 4th)